# Unable to find projectile in the package list

Tags: package, package-repositories

I have added these lines to a file `~/.emacs.d/package_init.el`

```
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line
```

Then I both restarting `aquamacs` and runing `m-x package-initialize`, but I fail to find `projectile` in the listing. Here is a partial screenshot of the result of `m-x package-list-packages`

[image]

I have confirmed that this package exists on MELPA http://stable.melpa.org/#/projectile

What have I done wrong? How can I install this package?

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like this has nothing to do with projectile. *None* of the Melpa packages show up in your list. Could you edit your question/title to reflect that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What have I done wrong? How can I install this package?

You said you added this configuration to a file called
`~/.emacs.d/package_init.el`, but Emacs will do nothing to load this
file by itself. If you want the configurations to take effect, you
need to either put them in `~/.emacs.d/init.el` or add a line
like the following inside your `init.el`:

```
(load (locate-user-emacs-file "package_init.el"))
```

Comment: You can use locate-user-emacs-file instead of expanding against user-emacs-directory.

Comment: @lunaryorn true. Not to mention the snippet I had wss just wrong. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Check `*Messages*` for any errors that come up when you do `M-x package-initialize`. You might also try doing a `C-h v package-archives` to make sure that `http://melpa.org/packages/` is really there, and not getting removed somehow.

Comment: The URL is correct: `http://melpa.org/packages/` is the official URL of MELPA since some time.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I was following this and it works for me: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html

Comment: You should follow the [official documentation](http://melpa.org/#/getting-started).

Comment: I see... looks like it was changed in the last few months. I've edited my answer.